# Ordering based on the total of a related table in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have a number of baseball players.  They have played in a number of baseball games.  I wish to find the players on the Yankees and order them by the number of hit they have.  They are in a MySqlDatabase.

Here is the basic structure:

```
[Players]
ID      Name      Team
1       Jim       Yankees
2       Bob       Yankees
3       Ted       Red Socks
4       Hal       Yankees
5       Tom       Dodgers


[Games]
ID     Player_Id     Hits
1      1             2
2      2             0 
3      3             3 
4      4             1 
5      5             2  
6      1             0
7      2             0 
8      3             1 
9      4             4 
10     5             1 
11     1             0
12     2             0 
13     3             1 
14     4             3 
15     5             1
```

I am looking for the results

```
Hal      8
Jim      2
Bob      0
```

What is the query?

Comment: Have you tried to generate those results?  Please edit the question with your attempt.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Players Where Team ='Yankees' ORDER BY  SUM (Games.Hits)  ;   This is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT playerName ,totalHits
FROM players p
INNER JOIN

(
SELECT player_ID,SUM(Hits) as totalHits
FROM games
GROUP BY player_ID
) as g

ON p.ID=g.player_ID
WHERE p.team='Yankees'
ORDER BY totalHits desc
```

Comment: Hi, Is there a specific name for this kind of technique, where we are joining a view with a table??

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would consider the better solution:

```
SELECT p.Name, sum(Hits) as TotalHits
FROM Players p LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Games g
     on p.id = g.player_id
WHERE p.Team = 'Yankees'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY TotalHits DESC;
```

What do I consider this better?

- In MySQL, a subquery is materialized.  This results in unnecessary overhead.
- By not using a materialized view, MySQL has a better opportunity to use indexes for the join.
- The use of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` guarantees that all Yankees players will be included, even those not in the `Games` table.

Comment: why is that in SQL Server this will throw column p.name not in group by or aggregate function error while it is not so in mysql ... does it change meaning of aggregate result .. mysql allows for just about any column list in select clause and group by clause ... would be helpful if you can explain it in edit of your answer ..